# Are Apache HBase and Cloudera HBase compatible?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, elastic-map-reduce

At work we are attempting to do the following:

- Run Elastic MapReduce jobs via Amazon, which freezes Hadoop at version 0.20.205
- Write output to HBase running on EC2, specifically, 0.92.1-cdh4.0.1 from Cloudera

What I've discovered so far is my WordCount test appears to work when I use Apache HBase 0.92.1 in my Hadoop job (packaged via maven).  I'm scared that this is working accidentally and that may blow up as my usage matures.

However, when I package HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.0.1 in my Hadoop job, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`:

https://emr-qa.eventbrite.com.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/j-RWJ75VR11SLB/steps/1/stderr

- Does the Apache HBase jar play nicely with the CDH Hbase server?
- Is mixing versions and packages like this is horrible idea?

Comment: Looks like the answer is "no"...from one of the HBase committers: http://bit.ly/PqwNqD

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it seems they are not compatible (there's a problem in the connections). The solution is to change the maven dependency to use cloudera's jars:

```
 <properties>
   <hbase.version>0.92.1-cdh4.0.1</hbase.version>
   <hadoop.version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.1</hadoop.version>
 </properties>

 <repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>cloudera</id>
       <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

And later in the dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version} </version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <artifactId>thrift</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

You can change the property and repackage when you want to use the code with another distro